# How to move entire project board into a different repository?

Tags: github, repository

I want to move a project board (cards and all) from the top level of my account under "projects" into a specific repository I made, because as of now they are not linked at all. The project board was intended for that repository before I made it.

EDIT: Let me try to be clear. First I made the project board. This is under the "Projects" directory.  I filled it up with lots of "To Do", "In Progress", and "Done" cards. Then I linked my local project directory to GitHub as a new repository. If I go into that repository on the GitHub website, I see there is a link to "Projects" WITHIN that repository, but it says there are 0 Projects. I want my project boards to be there.

Comment: look at this article. https://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2011/09/12/moving-one-git-repo-into-another-as-subdirectory/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this article applies since there are no files to move (is a board even classified as a "repository?"), the project boards are entirely a feature of the gitHub front end.